# isn't number localization just unnecessary?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, vb.net

I've just read this page http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

One of the things they did was to convert the arabic date to the arabic calendar. I'm wondering if it is a good idea at all to do so. Will it actually be annoying/confusing for the user (even if the user is Arabic).

Also, my second question is that do we really need to change 3,899.99 to 3.899,99 for some cultures like German? I mean it doesn't hurt to do so since the library already does it for us but wouldn't this actually cause more confusion to the user (even if he is German).

I'm sure whatever culture these people come from, if i give you a number 3,899.99 there's no way you'd get that wrong right? (since he'd probably learned the universal format anyway)

Comment: In China, though I can read 1,000,000 with no problem, but say 100,0000 would be even better. Because, there is no Chinese word for `million`, a `million` is 100 `wan`s.

Comment: heys all i've moved the thread to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75061/isnt-number-localization-just-unnecessary

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik I know, i'm chinese too. but if i see an app write 1,000,000 its 1 million alright. if i see an app write 100,0000 now part of me would be worried if it was some kind of software error (especially if money is involved). since everyone is doing 1,000,000, or if i see a 100,0000 it'll definitely raise some suspicion nevertheless. so isn't it better just to use 1,000,000 ?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem here seems to be a bad assumption. There is no "universal format" for numbers. 3,899.99 is valid in some places, and confusing in others. Same for the converse. People can often figure out what they need to (especially if it's in software that is clearly doing a shoddy job of localization otherwise. :) ), but that's not the point.

Except in certain scientific and technical domains that general software doesn't usually address, there's no universal format for any of these things. If you want your software to be accepted on native terms anywhere but your own place, you'll need to work for it.

Comment: actually i meant "universal" as the format that everyone will see and know what it means. To be sure 1.234,00 is definitely not universal. I mean i'm very sure you can find someone who have never seen this number format in all their lifes. since most apps had been using 1,234.00 without localization i believed that it has been the de-facto (the universal format that everyone will see and know what it means). this is what i call globalization

Comment: @Pacecrier: Nope. You can call that globalization, but you'd be absolutely wrong to do so. That format is not, in fact, universal, and there are people out there who have never seen it. Assume a consistent US-English (or something like it) worldview at your peril.

Answer (score 5):

To me it seems like it would be much less confusing to see dates and numbers in the format you're used to (in your country or language) - why do you think it would be the other way around?

Answer (score 4):

The point of localization is to make your application look more natural for the user.  It is definitely advisable to do this in your application if you use it internationally.  While you can use US standards, that is not very customer-friendly way of doing things.

How would it be more confusing to a person to see the format they are familiar with?  Meet people where they are with your application.  If their standard is 10.000,00 and you are showing them 10,000.00, even if they understand it, it does make it a bit disconcerting.  Reverse the situation and think what you would like.  Would you like a developer using 10.000,00 for their application because you can understand it just fine?

Comment: actually the reason its not fine is because 10.000,00  look like an Error to me (i will think its $10 instead of $10,000), whereas 10,000.00 won't feel like an error to anyone at all since its universal

Answer (score 4):

Depends. `3.899,99` to me looks like two numbers. `3.899` and `99`. I imagine our number formatting looks similarly funny to foreigners. Sure, I could guess what it means here, but what if you had a whole bunch of numbers like this clustered together? The winning lotto numbers are 45,26,21,56,94,13. Is that one big number, or 6 2-digit numbers?

Date formatting is especially important. 01/02/03. Is that Jan 2 2003, Feb 1 2003, Feb 3 2001 or what? Different cultures specify the d/m/y in different orders. Also, when spelled out, they obviously have different names for the months.

If you have the time and resources to internationalize it, I think you should.

Comment: obviously we would avoid 01/02/03. but no one can get Jan 2 2003, Feb 1 2003, Feb 3 2001 wrong if we wrote them as such right. If the language is different, i believe its a matter of internationalization and not localization which specifically was the problem im asking about.

Answer (score 3):

As a foreigner myself, I can assure you that localization helps a lot in terms of user satisfaction. Commas or dots in numbers may induce big mistakes. Another on is the relative position of days and months.
To improve even further, create translations and add an option to choose locale. That way you will have close to 100% customer satisfaction

Comment: just curious. what country are you from?

Comment: @Pacerier lol Argentina. We use commas to separate thousands, dots for decimals, 24 h time format and day/month/year calendar. It took me quite some time to get used to the US locale!

Comment: now i do have some personal questions. If i give you a number 10,000.50 do you have to think twice before you know its 10,000.50 and if i give you a date **2 Jan 2003** do you need to think twice to tell that date? what if the date is **Jan 2 2003** ?

Comment: @Pacerier, if it says "Jan", then there is no doubt about it. It just can't be a day, so there is no discussion there. But if you say 1/2/2003, then yes, I need to think it twice some times. On the number, I can tell you that a few years ago, I would have had to read it a few times. Now, I've been in the States for too long so I'm not a good sample anymore.

Comment: no i'll never use formats like 1/2/2003 they just don't make sense. but either **Jan 2 2003** (month first) or **2 Jan 2003** (month middle) or **2003 Jan 2** (year first) would be clear wouldn't it..

Answer (score 3):

another important thing is input. if you don't have localization, take the user input "1.234"... what does the user mean? 1.234 or 1234 ? ... there may be users that don't like their values to be off by factor 1000 ... who knows? ;)

Comment: if i want an integer and u put 1.234 i won't guess, its just wrong input and deserves an error. i actually believe that if the user writes 1.234 he means 1.234 and not 1234. Especially when money is involved, he would be sure that he would write in a universal way.. if the app changes what sense it makes out of user input just because of a change of localization wouldn't it be more confusing to the user instead of accepting just 1 form of (universal) input?

Comment: @Pacerier, the problem is that **there is no "universal way"**. There is the US way, and there are many other ways.